# executar comandos docker/docker-compose em pasta externa

Tags: php, docker

Criei um servidor LAMP simples usando docker/docker-compose, consegui inicializar os containers apontando para uma pasta externa à que estão os arquivos do docker, o problema é que preciso rodar alguns comandos, como o composer, na pasta de cada projeto e como o arquivo `docker-compose.yml` está numa pasta externa isso não é possível, como posso rodar os comandos com pastas externas?

exemplificando:

arquivos do docker (Dockerfile e docker-compose.yml):

```
/home/thiago/docker/lamp
```

pastas de vários projetos diferentes:

```
/home/thiago/www/ (várias pastas, exemplo: projeto1, projeto2, projeto3)
```

exemplo de uso do composer com docker (na pasta relativa ao projeto):

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER composer install
```

tentei adicionar a flag --workdir /home/thiago/www/projeto1/

mas o seguinte erro é retornado:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/home/thiago/www/projeto1\") set in config.json failed: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u 1000 -d /home/sammy sammy
RUN mkdir -p /home/sammy/.composer && \
    chown -R sammy:sammy /home/sammy
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    www:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - $HOME/www/:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - mysql
        networks:
            - default
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root 
        volumes:
            - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - ./conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
            - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
volumes:
    persistent:
```

Comment: Você está tentando usar um ambiente docker para todos os projetos? Pelo meu entendimento a ideia do docker (ainda mais com o docker-compose) é para ter um ambiente "containerizado" para cada projeto. Para usar um ambiente compartilhado pode se melhor usar apache e mysql do sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o command do docker composer, assim toda verz antes de iniciar ele roda um comando

Lembrando que o comando que você quer rodar precisa de um bash por isso estou chamando antes o /bin/bash, mas pode ser quanquer outro como o binario sh  /bin/sh

Para o serviço ficar rodando você precisa de uma aplicação demon no caso aqui é o `php server`, se deixar apenas o `composer install` o docker rodaria o comando e assim que terminace de executar pararia

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    www:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
        command:  /bin/bash -c "composer install &&  php server"
        volumes:
            - $HOME/www/:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - mysql
        networks:
            - default
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root 
        volumes:
            - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - ./conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
            - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
volumes:
    persistent:
```